# Xcode error: Comparison between pointer and double

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, pointers

I'm trying to write a program using an array to store scores for 6 tests and then adding a curve the grade, then displaying the final score. I keep getting an error from Xcode that there's a "comparison between a pointer and integer ('int' and double'*')" in the for loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    const int test = 5;    //sets the number of tests
    double score[test];      //array to hold each tests score
    double curve;           //curve for the tests
    double finalScore;      //The final test scores after the curve is applied

    //Input scores of the tests
    cout << "Enter the scores for \n";
    for (int test = 0; test < score; test++)
    {
         cout << "test #" << (test+1) <<": ";
         cin >> score[test];
    }

    //input the curve
    cout << "\nAll of these tests will have the same curve applied."
    << "\nEnter the curve: ";
    cin >> curve;

    //display the modified test scores
    cout << "\nHere are the curve test scores:\n";
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    for (int test = 0; test < score; test++)
    {
        finalScore = score[test] + curve;
        cout << "Test #" << (test + 1) << ": " << setw(7) << finalScore <<      endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `test < score` does?

Comment: `for (int test = 0; test < score; test++)`-> `for (int test = 0; test < 5; test++)`

Comment: This doesn't directly address the problem, but having an array size named `test` and a loop control variable named `test` is rather confusing. You need to run the loop from 0 up to the array size `test`, and giving the loop control variable a different name would make it much clearer. Or, probably better, give the array size a better name.

Comment: Sticking with the poor name `test` for now, you probably want `for (int i = 0;  i < test;  ++i) { finalScore = score[i] + curve; /* etc */ }` or the like.  But really, use better names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double score[5]` defines an array of doubles, and `score` denotes the address of the first element of this array; hence, it is a pointer and `int test=0; test < score` compares an integral value with a pointer value; Therefore the error / the warning.

Distinguish the `nrOfTests` from the variable used for iterating the tests, e.g. `test`:

```
const int nrOfTests = 5;    //sets the number of tests
double score[nrOfTests];      //array to hold each tests score

....

for (int test = 0; test < nrOfTests; test++) { 
    ...
}

....

for (int test = 0; test < nrOfTests; test++) { 
    ...
}
```